# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Template

Tags: wordpress

found some help on here earlier today and hoping to do so again about creating a custom template. :-)

I have a Wordpress custom post type set up in my functions.php

I have a custom taxonomy called "Classifications"

Under that taxonomy I have the terms/categories:

Old Research (parent)
--- sub cat 1
--- sub cat 2

I have created the file "taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php" which successfully changes the layout for me. However, it does not hold the layout in the sub categories. I can alter it by also creating "taxonomy-Classifications-subcat1-oldresearch.php" but I will have a lot of sub categories that I want to use one template for. This way I don't have to create a new template file for every new category. Does anyone have a good solution for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [great post on the Wordpress stack exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71285) that addresses exactly this issue. The problem is that Wordpress uses a [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to load php templates based on the slugs of each term.

Comment: That post was very helpful, but my dilemma still exists. I have appropriate files for "taxonomy-taxonomyname.php" and my parent cat template "taxonomy-taxonomyname-parentcat.php". The problem is when I load the page for any sub category of my parent category it reverts back to "taxonomy-taxonomyname.php"rather than "taxonomy-taxonomyname-parentcat.php". I could create additional templates for the sub-cats but I don't want to. I'd rather them use "taxonomy-taxonomyname-parentcat.php"

Answer (score 0):

You can do some custom coding inside your taxonomy template to show proper sub categories as you want. For example, let suppose your current parent taxonomy is `oldresearch` then you will be taken to specific taxonomy template as WordPress does, in your case you will be taken to `oldresearch` template page. Inside that template you can get `id` of your current term and then can get children data from that category. In code it will look something like shown below:
**Note**: this below code is for reference you can use it according to your needs.

```
<?php
$term_id = 10;
$taxonomy_name = 'Classifications';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' .     $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

In this way you can play with your sub-categories data. `$term_id` is just for reference purposes, you will be getting id of your `parent taxonomy term` and so will be getting sub categories from that term. 
For further reading check [Get Children terms Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)